# Is retrieving HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\MachineGuid only achievable by reading the registry?

Tags: c#, .net, registry

Is retrieving

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\MachineGuid
```

only achievable by reading the registry?

Is it perhaps stored or exposed in static class exposed by a .NET library provided by Microsoft?

Comment: Despite its name, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\MachineGuid` is [not actually unique](http://www.eigo.co.uk/News-Article.aspx?NewsArticleID=63). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Tell environments apart, not machines, so if it is unique per Windows installation, that's good enough for me.

Comment: Keep it simple, just create your own with the Guid type.  Store it in the registry or a file.

Answer (score 0):

I think so, retrieving such information is only achievable by reading the registry.